# 1 domain 2 websites

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

There are 2 different websites in 2 directories `..path/siteA/` and `..path/siteB/` . I need to load one of them on domain `example.com` depending on their country they are visiting from.

It can't be `www.example.com/siteA` it must be `www.example.com` .

Is it posible?

Edit: found the solution.

Comment: Is it the same website in two langauges or two entirely different pages?

Comment: And if I want to give the URL of your site to an english person visiting France, I'll have no way to give him the address of the *english* website, it'll incorrectly assume he is french. Even if he using his browser indicating servers he prefers english content before anything else. Language detection is OK, not country (though difficult)

Comment: I don't care about that. This is not a problem

Comment: You don't care about inconveniences to your users?

Comment: it will be thinked about later. This is not what I am asking now

Comment: Can you post the solution you discovered?

Answer (score 0):

Configure Your webserver to listen on two different ports, one pourt should serve content from /path/siteA and the second one from /path/siteB.

Next step is to configure Pound depending on the location of the user (IP geolocalisation) and You're on Your way

Comment: I can't configure to listen to different port. No full access to server.

Comment: Using different ports definitely isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually done with geo-location.

You use a redirect on example.com/index.php that redirects to example.com/pathA or example.com/pathB depending on their ip

use the `header()` function to redirect :)

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(...) // check location of IP
{
  header("Location: /pathA");
}
else
{
  header("Location: /pathB");
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

---

Edit:
Based on comment, this is what you need: [mod_Rewrite: Filter specific pages by IP and redirect them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391685/mod-rewrite-filter-specific-pages-by-ip-and-redirect-them)

Comment: redirection is not what i need. "It can't be www.example.com/siteA it must be www.example.com . "

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.  First pages you have to ask the language or show the default language.

This is done by two methods:

1. Each language can be lines or words assigned in separately files with each variables.  By using the variable calling we can the get the language parameter.
2. Each language can be lines or words assigned in database with separately table.

Comment: it is not about the language.

Comment: Here language as taken as like country.  Find the ip of the country and do the above procedure for the country.